# Regex for letters and no spaces

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

Hi I am trying to learn REGEX expressions to validate that the user has entered only one word of their name i.e First name = Anthony
no spaces, special characters or numbers at all.
what I have right now is

```
 var re = /[A-Za-z]/;
  // Check input
  if(re.test(document.getElementById('realname').value)){
    // Style green
    document.getElementById('realname').style.border ='1px solid green';
    // Hide error prompt
    document.getElementById('realnameError').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('realnameEmptyError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else if(!document.getElementById('realname').value) {
     document.getElementById('realnameError').style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById('realnameEmptyError').style.display = "block";
  }
```

Comment: `var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;`

Comment: Please edit to specify the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add anchors and also add `+` next to the charcater class.

```
var re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
```

`^` - start

`[A-Za-z]+` - One or more letters

`$`- End

Comment: What does the plus do if the end is directly after it?

Comment: `+` repeats the previous pattern one or more times. So `[A-Za-z]+` should match a single letter or group of letters

Answer (score 1):

To accept just letters you have to use a character class and add `a-zA-Z` into it:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the first letter in upper case this would be the regex.

**Regex:** `^[A-Z][a-z]{1,15}$`

**Explanation:**

- `[A-Z]` matches first upper case letter.
- `[a-z]{1,15}` matches rest of the letters. Using `+` will allow **many** characters. You can set the upper limit.
- Anchor `^` and `$` makes sure that whole string is a match and not **part** of whole string.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sM4hP7/1)**