# refactoring my JavaScript code to remove more then just white space

Tags: javascript

The following code is functional but I would like to refactor the !== part that allows my ternary to run only on values that are not white space so I can include edge case test's. This would include any non letter value as well as white space and I know that regex may play a part but I can't find a niftty way to incorporate it into the if() statement that precedes the ternary operations.

```js
const letterPositions = function(strPos) {
  if (typeof strPos !== 'string') {
    return console.log('Sorry your input is not a string');
  }

  const result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < strPos.length; i++) {
    if (strPos[i] !== ' ') {
      result[strPos[i]] ? result[strPos[i]].push(i) : (result[strPos[i]] = [i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(letterPositions('aa bb cc'));
```

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073176/javascript-regex-only-english-letters-allowed), but that question's answer doesn't do a very good job of explaining the code.

Comment: well I'm wondering if it possible to add a similar statement to my code in the !== part with out having to re-declare a variable.

Comment: RegEx aside you could add conditions to the if statement using the AND operator (&&). Both of your edge cases have been solved using RegEx [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548851/regex-for-letters-and-no-spaces)

Comment: @HopeWarren Yes, you can pass `strPos[i]` to `test()`. There is no difference whether you pass a string literal or a reference to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do that...

```js
const letterPositions = str =>
  {
  if (typeof str !== 'string') 
    return console.log('Sorry your input is not a string' )
 
  return [...str].reduce((r,l,i)=>((l===' ')?null:(r[l]??=[],r[l].push(i)),r),{})
  }

console.log( letterPositions('aa bb cc') )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: I really do love the reduce function. Tyvm!

Answer (score 1):

mainly two options, regex and charcode, welcome to edit if more ways available

```js
const codes = ['A', 'Z', 'a', 'z'].map(x => x.charCodeAt(0))
console.log(codes)

const letterPositions = function(strPos) {
  if (typeof strPos !== 'string') {
    return console.log('Sorry your input is not a string');
  }

  const result = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < strPos.length; i++) {

    //if (strPos[i] !== ' ') {                       // old

    //if (/[A-Za-z]/.test(strPos[i])) {                 // regex

    let code = strPos.charCodeAt(i)
    if ((code >= 65 && code <= 90) || (code >= 97 && code <= 122)) { // charcode
      result[strPos[i]] ? result[strPos[i]].push(i) : (result[strPos[i]] = [i]);
    }
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(letterPositions('aa bb cc'));
```